# Grant y currency items when x number of minutes have expired since the play

Tags: database, performance, timer, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table of users with a 'lastPlay' Field, I want to grant y currency items when x number of minutes have expired since the play.

The most straightforward way to do this would be to have a query running every second/minute to check if the time has expired since the last play for each user. But this approach seems brutish as the entire table would be scanned and each user parsed nearly every second.

Another approach would be to create a timer for each individual user, but the number of timers that are running would grow too large as the number of users increases.

Is there any other approach that someone could suggest? Can I place some sort of trigger on the database(DynamoDB)?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two broad approaches to solve this problem.

> But this approach seems brutish as the entire table would be scanned and each user parsed nearly every second.

One of the ways you could resolve this problem is by using global secondary indices. Say that along with the 'lastPlay' field, you have another field called 'partition'. Let's also say that the 'lastPlay' field is formatted as an ISO-8601 timestamp with UTC as timezone. Let's say that the 'partition' field is always set to the prefix of 'lastPlay' value obtained by truncating everything after the minutes.  For example, if 'lastPlay' has the value '2015-06-01T01:23:45.000Z', then 'partition' has the value '2015-06-01T01'. You can now set up a global secondary index with 'partition' has the hash key and 'lastPlay' as the range key. To find out all the records that has the lastPlay value within a certain time range, you can query this global secondary index. If the time range you are querying over spans multiple adjacent hours, query the global secondary index multiple times, once for each hour.

One drawback of this solution is that if you have a lot of players having value for lastPlay within the same hour, then the global secondary index would get hot because those players wouldn't be [properly distributed over the entire index space](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.UniformWorkload). You can remedy that by letting 'partition' be calculated by truncating 'lastPlay' at minutes instead of hours. Another remedy is to add a randomly generated suffix to the end of 'partition'. See the section 'Using a Calculated Value' [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.UniformWorkload).

> Can I place some sort of trigger on the database(DynamoDB)?

AWS Lambda is the general thing that provides this kind of feature. [This page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/wt-ddb.html) talks about how you can react to changes in DynamoDB. You can use this to find out if the 'lastUpdated' field has changed on any record. Once you know this, you can use another service to create a timer that will be triggered in the future for you. An example of such a service is AWS SQS. SQS is a message queuing service. One of the features that SQS provides is [delay queues](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-delay-queues.html). This allows message retrieval from queue to be delayed for up to 15 minutes after the message is added to the queue. Some sort of rudimentary timer could potentially be built over this, but it is not trivial.

Comment: I did a version of the 1st method, running a scan with two filter expressions every minute. I'm not sure how expensive or scalable the scan is moving forward. But I've also lost accuracy on when the currency was supposed to granted ~1min